# Tweak Visual Studio open file Tabs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In VS2008, specifically:

- Is it possible to add "close all" as well as "close all but this"?
- Can we add a close button to each tab, like in FF, rather than having to right-click?

Comment: There is a plugin for VS 2010, not sure about 2008: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 0):

> - Is it possible to add "close all" as well as "close all but this"?

That's spelled "Window/Windows", <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, "Close Window(s)"

> - Can we add a close button to each tab, like in FF, rather than having to right-click?

I don't think there's anything built in for this, and I doubt that any plugin could tweak the UI that much. You might make a feature request, though.

Comment: CTRL+A is select all in my near-default setup. I see the option in Windows menu, so I guess I can assign a custom shortcut though.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) add Close All to tab context menu. [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) add-in (developed by me) add a close button to each tab.